SQL Merge statement on a "Join Table" of a many-to-many relationship
As a title says - I have two tables, Address with the key addrId (int, identity), and Company with the key coId (int, identity).
The relationship between them is many-to-many, so I have a 3rd table CompanyAddress with the primary key ID (int, identity) and foreign keys coId and addrId.
I have a stored procedure that takes JSON input containing address data for a single company - so it could be a JSON array of the form (note the same CompanyID):
[
   {
        "CompanyId": 123545,
        "Address1": "123 Street ",
        "Address2": ""
        "City": "New York",
        "PostalCode": " 10016",
        "StateAbrv": "NY"
    },
      {
        "CompanyId": 123545,
        "Address1": "459 Another Street ",
        "Address2": ""
        "City": "Another city",
        "PostalCode": "zip code",
        "StateAbrv": "ST"
    }
]

The stored procedure then uses a MERGE statement to insert new address into table Address, or update the address if it existed.
The assumption is that the company used already present in the table Company.
Upon that completion, I want to update the join table and I think, I want use the MERGE statement. However, I do not know what to use as a source of the merge.
So, statement would be like this
MERGE CompanyAddress AS trgt
USING <SOURCE WITH BOTH AddressId and Company ID> AS src
ON <merge condition>

After previous merge, I know that the address is already present in table Address, but I do not know if it is "new" address (inserted, then Max(ID)) or updated .. (How do I get ID).  Also, at this point, the company name only available as part of the incoming Json, how do I link it to a table Company?
I have a sense that the SOURCE WITH BOTH AddressId and Company ID should be a temporary table obtained as a join of something but, can't exactly put a finger on it.

In your initial MERGE Address ...statement, you can use the OUTPUT clause to capture a combination of src.CompanyId and inserted.AddressId that can be saved to a temporary table or table variable (that you defined earlier). Than can then be used to feed the MERGE CompanyAddress ... statement.  See this answer for an example.

As a side note, you mention that the Company to Address relationship is many-to-many,  but you also state that you are using MERGE to update existing addresses. This could lead to unexpected data inconstancies if you update an address row that is shared by more than one company.

Thank you, very much !!  It worked perfectly.
To your second comment, I know of that.  But it won't be an problem, it is taken care on application level.  The merge part is only for the database side.

How can you update an address? There is no AddressId in the JSON so no way of uniquely identifying it.

Address table has an Identity ID.  And in the merge condition, I  specify what constitutes the "unique" address

Well how about you show that because at the moment we have no idea.

And what do you want to happen if the same address is in two companies, or if the address exists but no link via CompanyAddress? A new Address row for each or reuse the same one?

The goal is to maintain a  store address coming via ETL from various sources.  So Address ID (identity), company ID are not related to source ID.
Address can exist without the company.  When the relationship occurs, that is when it is created/updated
In the merge statement "On" clause, I use the following, and it is enough for now.
ON src.Address1 = trgt.[AddressLine1] and src.Address2 = trgt.[AddressLine2]
and src.City = trgt.City and src.State = trgt.StateOrProvince and src.CountryName = trgt.CountryName
This would take care of the "same" address.

So what do you actually want to update, if all the fields are the same? Why is this not just two simple INSERTs? Why is MERGE needed at all, if you are not updating anything?

@Charlieface, I am sorry I did not understand your last comment.
If rows are the same I "do not want" to update anything, but I do not know when rows the same or not.  So it looked  like a MERGE can work, since it is simpler than "checking" if the row exists in a table and running insert if not ( and not do anything if it does).  Besides, the full set of fields in the incoming dataset could be more than the columns I am checking as keys, so if they change, I'd like to catch that change.

It doesn't appear you need a MERGE here as you only want to insert, not update.
You can shred the JSON using OPENJSON, then do two joined INSERTs, checking for existing rows using NOT EXISTS.
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
   {
        "CompanyId": 123545,
        "Address1": "123 Street ",
        "Address2": ""
        "City": "New York",
        "PostalCode": " 10016",
        "StateAbrv": "NY"
    },
      {
        "CompanyId": 123545,
        "Address1": "459 Another Street ",
        "Address2": ""
        "City": "Another city",
        "PostalCode": "zip code",
        "StateAbrv": "ST"
    }
]';

INSERT dbo.Address
  (Address1, Address2, City, PostalCode, StateAbrv)
SELECT
  j.Address1,
  j.Address2,
  j.City,
  j.PostalCode,
  j.StateAbrv
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    Address1 nvarchar(100),
    Address2 nvarchar(100),
    City nvarchar(100),
    PostalCode nvarchar(20),
    StateAbrv nvarchar(10)
  ) j
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Address a
    WHERE a.Address1 = j.Address1
      AND a.Address2 = j.Address2
      AND a.City = j.City
      AND a.PostalCode = j.PostalCode
      AND a.StateAbrv = j.StateAbrv
);

INSERT dbo.CompanyAddress
  (CompanyId, AddressId)
SELECT
  j.CompanyId,
  a.AddressId
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    CompanyId bigint,
    Address1 nvarchar(100),
    Address2 nvarchar(100),
    City nvarchar(100),
    PostalCode nvarchar(20),
    StateAbrv nvarchar(10)
  ) j
JOIN dbo.Company c ON c.CompanyId = j.CompanyId
JOIN dbo.Address a
  ON a.Address1 = j.Address1
 AND a.Address2 = j.Address2
 AND a.City = j.City
 AND a.PostalCode = j.PostalCode
 AND a.StateAbrv = j.StateAbrv
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.CompanyAddress ca
    WHERE ca.CompanyId = j.CompanyId
      AND ca.AddressId = a.AddressId
);

A MERGE would look like this, although what the UPDATE part would look like is not clear.
WITH json AS (
    SELECT j.*
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
      WITH (
        Address1 nvarchar(100),
        Address2 nvarchar(100),
        City nvarchar(100),
        PostalCode nvarchar(20),
        StateAbrv nvarchar(10)
      ) j
)
MERGE dbo.Address a
USING json j
   ON a.Address1 = j.Address1
  AND a.Address2 = j.Address2
  AND a.City = j.City
  AND a.PostalCode = j.PostalCode
  AND a.StateAbrv = j.StateAbrv
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (Address1, Address2, City, PostalCode, StateAbrv)
  VALUES
    (j.Address1, j.Address2, j.City, j.PostalCode, j.StateAbrv)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET ????;  --  what goes here?

